# Why use iter = lst.insert(iter, word) and not just lst.insert(iter, word)

Tags: c++

I'm still learning about `insert()` on C++.

Why use `iter =` here?

```cpp
list<string> lst;
auto iter = lst.begin();
while (cin >> word)
    iter = lst.insert(iter, word);
```

Why not like this?

```cpp
list<string> lst;
auto iter = lst.begin();
while (cin >> word)
    lst.insert(iter, word);
```

I'm confused because there is also this case, which doesn't use `slist.begin() =`:

```cpp
list<string> slist;
slist.insert(slist.begin(), "Hello!");
```

Comment: please post proper code, not code with unnecessary syntax errors. `1st` is not a valid name

Comment: Perhaps what you're looking for is something like [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) which can be used together with the iterator-overload of the [`std::list` constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/list)?

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number But the book use that as the name... which is also confusing for me

Comment: Also, the default container type for almost all uses should be `std::vector` (or `std::array`). What book are you reading which teaches `std::list` instead? And using invalid names?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude No, that confusing code is my question, I don't understand it much. Its from C++ primer

Comment: Its probably `lst` instead of `1st` unless there was an error in the book.

Comment: C++ Primer (by Stanley Lippman, Josée Lajoie, and Barbara E. Moo) is a recommended book. I didn't expect such sloppy code from it. Unlike  C++ Primer Plus by Stephen Prata, which is *not* recommended and I would expect have such problems. I do hope you're using the first (C++ Primer) and not the second (C++ Primer Plus).

Comment: I'm changing the 1st to lst. And... can anyone tell me why its use the```iter =```?

Comment: Please read about what [the `std::list::insert` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/insert) *returns*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference becomes immediately apparent when you look at the output of the following input:

```
1
2
3
```

A:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::list<std::string> st;
    auto iter = st.end();
    std::string word;
    while (cin >> word)
        iter = st.insert(iter, word);

    for (const auto& w : st) std::cout << w << " ";
}
```

output:

```
3 2 1
```

B:

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::list<std::string> st;
    auto iter = st.end();
    std::string word;
    while (cin >> word)
        st.insert(iter, word);

    for (const auto& w : st) std::cout << w << " ";
}
```

output:

```
1 2 3
```

Note that I used `end()` instead of `begin()`, because `begin()` looks a little fishy when there is no element yet in the list. However, for an empty list, `begin() == end()`, so it does not change the result.

`std::list::insert()` inserts the element before the one referenced by the iterator you pass, and then returns an iterator to the newly inserted element. Hence, A inserts the next element always before the last element that was inserted. On the other hand, B always inserts the next element at the end of the list, because `iter` always points to the list's `end`.